# "http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse - is not present in the configuration" when defining WS02 proxy

Tags: jms, wso2, oracle-aq

I got  the example listed in http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2011/11/configuring-wso2-esb-with-oracle-as-messaging-media/
to work under bare-bone synapse. Now trying to get it to work in WS02.

In synapse I simply put the listed proxy in the synapse definitions file.
Here is how I've  tried doing it in WSO2:

1. Created a local entry as inline XML entry:

   Name: jmsMsgToSoapMsg_xslt

   Value: <localEntry key="jmsMsgToSoapMsg_xslt" src="file:jmsMsgToSoapMsg.xslt"/>
2. Then I tried creating a custom proxy by switching to the source view and pasting the proxy definition. However, when I hit "Save" I get an error:

   "Unable to generate data from source: Synapse namespace https://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse - is not present in the configuration."

That namespace is not referenced anywhere in the proxy. However, I noticed that it's being automatically inserted into the local entry defintion:

```
<localEntry xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="jmsMsgToSoapMsg_xslt" src="file:jmsMsgToSoapMsg.xslt"></localEntry>
```

and there is no way to delete it.
Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Comment: if that solves. add it as an answer. otherwise this shows as still unresolved

Answer (score 0):

Added xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" to the proxy xml which fixed the issue.